# how to configure slq server 2008 to allow remote authentication!

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-access

by using microsoft sql server management studio

Comment: not statements by visual... like we used to do for sql 2005 express

Comment: Could you be more specific? You want to enable Remote Connection for an SQL Server? If it's Express Edition, this is not possible, only connections from the local host will be accepted.

Comment: its evalution version.

Comment: cannot find the option which use enable mix mode authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using design view, using sql server mngmt stdio 08,

just right click on the server name,

goto security or connections and put a dot on allow mix mode...

Answer (score 2):

To enable remote access on an instance, you use the sp_configure system stored procedure.

```
exec sp_configure 'remote access', 1
reconfigure
```

This can be done against any instance from SQL Express to Data Center Edition.